# Visual Studio 2012 produces unresolved externals for xmm

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-2012, unresolved-external, sse

Ruby 1.9.1 fails to build with Visual Studio 2012 (update1 and 2) due to unresolved externals, when building with the default -arch:SSE compiler flag.

```
    cl -nologo -LD main.obj dmyext.obj msvcr110-ruby191-static.lib  msvcr110-ruby191.res unicows.lib oldnames.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ws2_32.lib  -Femsvcr110-ruby191.dll -link -incremental:no -debug -opt:ref -opt:icf   -implib:dummy.lib -def:msvcr110-ruby191.def -MAP:map-out.txt
Creating library dummy.lib and object dummy.exp
dummy.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000
dummy.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _xmm@7fffffffffffffff7fffffffffffffff
msvcr110-ruby191.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Opening the module definition file, the following register data items appear in the export section:

```
__xmm@80000000000000008000000000000000 DATA
__xmm@80000000800000008000000080000000 DATA
_xmm@41f00000000000000000000000000000 DATA
_xmm@7fffffffffffffff7fffffffffffffff DATA
```

The first two items preceded with two underscores do not cause an issue, but the last two items preceded with one underscore are responsible for the unresolved externals. Manually modifying the def file so that they all have two underscores seems to fix the problem, but I'm not sure if this is just hiding the problem or fixing the problem.

Another option is to build with the linker flag -force:unresolved, but this is dangerous if the unresolved externals are actually required.

A third option to fix this is to compile with the -arch:IA32 option, which will not produce SSE instructions. However, this ruby dll is also built for the x64 platform and there appears to be no way to successfully build x64 using an alternative -arch option.

My questions are:

Is it normal / expected that xmm register data appear as an export in the module definition file?

Are there any ideas on how to resolve this for Win32 and x64 platforms?

Answer (score 1):

This issue it now resolved.

It turns out that there is a ruby script called **mkexports.rb** that generates exports for the **msvcr110-ruby191.lib**.

In the function each_export, there is a line of code that excludes data items based on 8 - 16 hexadecimal digits, which successfully excludes __real data.

```
next if /(?!^)@.*@/ =~ l || /@[[:xdigit:]]{8,16}$/ =~ l || /^_DllMain@/ =~ l
```

Amended the code to exlude items based on 8 - 32 hexadecimal digits, which now excludes __xmm data, too.

```
next if /(?!^)@.*@/ =~ l || /@[[:xdigit:]]{8,32}$/ =~ l || /^_DllMain@/ =~ l
```